# Posts on newsfeed are coming out duplicated if it's your profile, posts of other users are coming out just once

Tags: java, android

I have the following problem. Posts of other users are coming out fine only one post. But if it's your profile, in the HomeFragment the posts are coming out duplicated and I am not sure why that is.

In my `readPosts();` method, if I get rid of this line `} else if (mFirebaseUser.getUid().equals(post.getPublisher())) {mPostLists.add(post);` it's fine, but then my posts don't show up only the posts of the people I follow. I need mine to show up also in the newsfeed, but just once not duplicated. All of my posts are being duplicated. Same post comes up twice on my feed. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Something I am doing wrong in my `readPosts();` method, but I am not sure what after having played around with it a bunch.

**HomeFragment**

```
public class HomeTabLayoutFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private PostAdapter mPostAdapter;
    private List<Post> mPostLists;

    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    private List<String> mFollowingList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_tab_layout, container, false);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        mProgressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mPostLists = new ArrayList<>();
        mPostAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), mPostLists);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);

        SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        checkIfUserExists();
        checkFollowing();

        return v;
    }

    private void checkIfUserExists() {
        if (mFirebaseAuth == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void checkFollowing() {
        mFollowingList = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Follow").child(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Following");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mFollowingList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mFollowingList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }

                readPosts();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readPosts() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mPostLists.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    for (String id : mFollowingList) {
                        if (post != null) {
                            if (post.getPublisher().equals(id)) {
                                mPostLists.add(post);
                            } else if (mFirebaseUser.getUid().equals(post.getPublisher())) {
                                mPostLists.add(post);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    mPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your inner loop in readPosts(). The loop is based on elements of mFollowingList. This condition has nothing to do with that:

```
if (mFirebaseUser.getUid().equals(post.getPublisher()))
```

It will be either true or false for every execution of the internal loop. Therefore, it may add more elements than you want. You probably want to put it in the outer loop, not the inner one - to execute it just once per post.

I'd make some more changes though. The check (post != null) can be done outside the loop. No need to let it loop multiple times for no reason. notifyDataSetChanged() also does not need to be inside any loop, it needs to be called once.

Extra regarding code style :-) - You're using too much indentation. It makes sense to extract things to a separate method for readability, it's a good idea to keep methods short, with descriptive names.

```
private void readPosts() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mPostLists.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);

                if (post != null && shouldAddPost(post)) {
                    mPostLists.add(post);
                }
            }

            mPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private boolean shouldAddPost(@NotNull Post post) {
    boolean isFollowingPublisher = false;
    for (String id : mFollowingList) {
        if (post.getPublisher().equals(id)) {
            isFollowingPublisher = true;
        }
    }

    boolean isPublisher = post.getPublisher().equals(mFirebaseUser.getUid());

    return isFollowingPublisher || isPublisher;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks man. Works perfecty. I see now that I was trying to execute the condition insude the Loop, but doing it outside the Loop would get me the same result right? And all I'd have to write is an if statement ```if (mFirebaseUser.getUid().equals(post.getPublisher()))``` and it saves me having to write another method, or no?

Comment: Bro, can you take a look at the answer that I posted and give me some feedback please. You think your method is more efficient? Same result... I think mine is a little bit easier on the eye. Let me know please!

Comment: The extra method does not make it any faster or slower. It makes it easier to read for most people. (and it's according to the guidelines that I follow). The reason is that it has a descriptive name, so the reader of your code will just look at it and know what't going on at a glance. They'll only go to the method if they want to know the details. Generally speaking, if you notice that you're using more than 3-4 levels of indentation in a method, you should consider simplifying it, and you had 7 in the original code.

Comment: Okay thanks man, I understand. Thanks for the explanation. But performance wise, in theory, both should execute the current task efficiently, right?

Comment: More or less the same performance. I could give you tips to improve it (in both cases), but that's completely unnecessary. This is very light code, and you should not worry too much about performance, but focus on readability (always write code so that someone else can understand it easily). Cheers!

Comment: Okay thanks buddy! I got it. Yeah I mean I want to make it as readable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void readPosts() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mPostLists.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    for (String id : mFollowingList) {
                        if (post != null) {
                            if (post.getPublisher().equals(id)) {
                                mPostLists.add(post);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (post != null)
                        if (mFirebaseUser.getUid().equals(post.getPublisher())) {
                            mPostLists.add(post);
                        }
                }

                mPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stan hey, can I get your feedback man. You don't think this way is better?

Comment: I guess it's OK, but it's not easier to understand, in my opinion. You can at least do an early "continue" when (post == null) to avoid checking twice. Also you're opening the door to a bug - if there are duplicate id's in mFollowingList, the post will be added more than once (it's a List, so it allows duplicate id's. You could use a Set instead to prevent that).

Comment: So use set instead of add. I'm going to research Set because I always use add, see what it does and differences. But so your method avoids these issues? Or same might / could happen?

Comment: Yeah, or alternatively you can exit the loop once you find a match (so it will add the post only once) - using break. (I said continue earlier by mistake)